# Subtract 1 hour from date in UNIX shell script

Tags: shell, datetime, unix

I have the following in a shell script.  How can I subtract one hour while retaining the formatting?

```
DATE=`date "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"`
```

Answer (score 99):

The following command works on recent versions of GNU `date`:

```
date -d '1 hour ago' "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"
```

Comment: i recieve -date: illegal option -- d
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
        date [-u] [+format]
        date -a [-]sss[.fff]

Comment: @shamir this means your version of date does not support this option.

Comment: i figure it out - i post it because may be you know some other way to do it on solaris machine?

Comment: @shamir, it may be easiest to just install GNU date.  You can use a different prefix or path so it doesn't conflict with the "official" one.  When I used to do a lot of work on Solaris, I installed a number of GNU utilities in my /home/karl/bin because they have these handy extra options.

Answer (score 19):

```
date -v-60M "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"

DATE=`date -v-60M "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"`
```

If you have bash version `4.4+` you can use bash's internal date printing and arithmetics:

```
printf "current date: %(%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S)T\n"
printf "date - 60min: %(%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S)T\n" $(( $(printf "%(%s)T") - 60 * 60 ))
```

The `$(printf "%(%s)T")` prints the epoch seconds, the `$(( epoch - 60*60 ))` is bash-aritmetics - subtracting 1hour in seconds. Prints:

```
current date: 04/20/2017 -18:14:31
date - 60min: 04/20/2017 -17:14:31
```

Comment: This is not portable, and relies on BSD `date` features.

Comment: @tripleee and which date is "portable"? Remember here are zillion BSD machines like MacOS. Linux (thanks god) aren't the only unix-like OS. Moreover, the second solution not using date at all... so...

Comment: The only option for [`date` specified in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html) is `-u`.  It might still not be fully portable, but that's a reasonable baseline. I'm not saying you have to come up with a solution, just pointing out a fact which might surprise visitors who try to use the information your answer.

Answer (score 12):

if you need substract with timestamp :

```
timestamp=$(date +%s -d '1 hour ago');
```

Comment: This is not portable, and relies on GNU `date` features.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ date +%Y-%m-%d-%H 
2019-04-09-20

$ date -v-1H +%Y-%m-%d-%H 
2019-04-09-19
```

But in shell use as like `date +%Y-%m-%d-%H`, `date -v-1H +%Y-%m-%d-%H`

Comment: The `-v` option looks like BSD `date` (which is what you get on macOS, too), not GNU `date`.

Answer (score 3):

This work on my Ubuntu 16.04 `date`:

`date --date="@$(($(date +%s) - 3600))" "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"`

And the `date` version is `date (GNU coreutils) 8.25`

Comment: This is not portable, and relies on GNU `date` features.

Answer (score 3):

If you need change timezone before subtraction with new format too:

```
$(TZ=US/Eastern date -d '1 hour ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

Comment: This is not portable, and relies on GNU `date` features.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to timestamp (a long integer), subtract the right number of milliseconds, reformat to the format you need.

Hard to give more details since you don't specify a programming language...

Comment: ahh.. i am using shell script, my formula go like this -DATE=`date "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"` and from DATE i want to subtract 1 hour

Comment: Are you required to stay in shell?  An inline awk or perl script could easily subtract an hour and output in your required format.

Answer (score 2):

Here another way to subtract 1 hour.

```
yesterdayDate=`date -d '2018-11-24 00:09 -1 hour' +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'` 
echo $yesterdayDate

Output:
2018-11-23 23:09
```

I hope that it can help someone.

Comment: This is not portable, and relies on GNU `date` features.

Answer (score -1):

```
DATE=date -1H "+%m/%d/%Y -%H:%M:%S"
```