# Using current timestamp at command line

Tags: shell

I have this command that works as expected:

```
aws cloudwatch get-metric-statistics \
    --region ap-south-1 \
    --namespace AWS/RDS \
    --metric-name DBLoad  \
    --period 60 \
    --statistics Average \
    --start-time 2023-06-12T01:00:00Z \
    --end-time 2023-06-12T23:00:00Z \
```

But I wish I could write something like this...

```
    --start-time now() - 12 hours \
    --end-time now() \
```

Is it possible to use now() in shell?

Comment: _Which_ shell? Have you read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5934394/3001761?

Comment: No. However, you can write your customized shell script. 
Check this post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6467/date-arithmetic-in-unix-shell-scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it in following way

```
    --start-time $(date -u -d '12 hour ago' +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ) \
    --end-time $(date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ) \
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Technically, you should also single quote the `date` format string, e.g. `+'....'`

Comment: Won't this give you a _local datetime_ that's formatted as if it's in UTC?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited as per your suggestion.